# SQLAlchemy find all rows with existing relationship

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an uploads table and upload_files table. With models Upload and UploadFiles. The upload_files has an upload_id field. And the upload model has a relationship set up to UploadFiles.

What I am trying to do is find all uploads which have existing entries in upload_files.

Basically this:

```
SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id IN (SELECT upload_id FROM upload_files)
```

But using the sqlalchemy models.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
query = Upload.query.filter(Upload.id == UploadFile.upload_id)
```

Then you can use `query.all` or `query.any` or other methods available on query object.

Comment: Thanks. Thats so simple it actually work :)

I also added a group_by(Upload.id) to reduce the number of records coming back from the DB to be dealt with by the python.